# How to get FolderBrowserDialog to show only Network

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Here is the code:

```
    private string SelectNetworkFolder(FolderBrowserDialog oFolderBrowserDialog)
    {
        Type type = oFolderBrowserDialog.GetType();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField("rootFolder", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        fieldInfo.SetValue(oFolderBrowserDialog, (Environment.SpecialFolder)18);
        oFolderBrowserDialog.Description = "Choose destination for the zip file(s)";

        PackageImagesViewModel viewModel = this.DataContext as PackageImagesViewModel;
        oFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = viewModel.GetMediaFolder();
        if (oFolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return oFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

This is where things get crazy -

1. If SelectedPath is set to a string that ends in a backslash, I get
   the Network and only that server - with the specified path selected.
2. If SelectedPath is set to a string that doesn't end with a
   backslash, I get everything from 1) plus 3 other workstations on my
   network (there should be around 700).
3. If I don't set SelectedPath, I get all the workstations on my network.

Anyone know how I can get all workstations listed and the current selection to be a specified folder?  One of the requirements is to show ONLY network shares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the product owner to change the requirements.  Now the user can pick **any** folder and will get an error if the folder isn't a network share.

```
    private void RadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PackageImagesViewModel viewModel = this.DataContext as PackageImagesViewModel;

        VistaFolderBrowserDialog d = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
        d.Description = "Please select a network share";
        d.SelectedPath = viewModel.GetMediaFolder();
        bool? pathSelected = d.ShowDialog();
        if (pathSelected == false)
            return;
        string value = GetUncPath(d.SelectedPath);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The selected folder is not recognized as a network path.", "Invalid Target Directory");
            return;
        }
        viewModel.DestinationFolder = value;
    }

    private string GetUncPath(string path)
    {
        if (path.StartsWith("\\"))
            return path;
        try
        {
            ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject();
            mo.Path = new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", path.Substring(0, 2)));

            // DriveType 4 = Network Drive
            if (Convert.ToUInt32(mo["DriveType"]) == 4)
                return Convert.ToString(mo["ProviderName"]) + path.Substring(2);
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
        catch { return string.Empty; }
    }
```