# Get network path not drive letter from FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

I have a winform with a `FolderBrowserDialog` to choose a folder from a network drive. The issue is that it returns the drive letter (`X:\Folder...`) rather than the network path (`\\Network\Projects\Folder...`). How can I get the network path?

Comment: What happens if you choose a network location that's not mapped to a drive?

Comment: See this other question, the answer is similar to what you're looking for : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818511/how-to-get-folderbrowserdialog-to-show-only-network)

Comment: @AdamV I'm not sure what happens if the location is not mapped. For my purposes, assume all network locations are mapped.

Comment: @Peter4499 This will help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty code that will show the path as a network path in a MessageBox. You may want to add additional checks and/or restructure this a bit.

```
using System.Management;

        var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.ShowDialog();

        var path = dialog.FileName;
        using (var managementObject = new ManagementObject())
        {
            managementObject.Path = new ManagementPath($"Win32_LogicalDisk='{path.Substring(0,2)}'");
            var driveType = (DriveType)(uint)managementObject["DriveType"];
            var networkPath = Convert.ToString(managementObject["ProviderName"]);
            

            if (driveType == DriveType.Network)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(path.Replace(path.Substring(0, 3), networkPath));
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(path);
```

Comment: I'm getting a System.TypeInitializationException on `var driveType = (DriveType)(uint)managementObject["DriveType"];`