# ManagementPath Class not working

Tags: c#, copy, getdrivetype

I am trying to get the name of a network drive (the relative path will not work with File.Copy). I found this [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687039/get-network-path-not-drive-letter-from-folderbrowserdialog) that suggests using DriveType. I'm having an issue with my project not recognizing the class. The Microsoft page says it is part of the current framework, I've got a using statement for System.Management, and I've got my target framework set at 4.6.1.

1. Is there something I'm missing that is preventing me from using this class?
2. Is there a better way to get the network drive path so File.Copy will work?

Comment: It is not a class in the .NET sense, you only ever use it in a string.  The compiler will never complain about a string.  We can't see what you are doing, that makes it too hard to help you.  Consider to use the WMI Code Creator utility to experiment, it can auto-generate the C# code you need.

Comment: Well, I can't use the ManagementPath() or ManagementObject() methods for some reason. `var managementObject = new ManagementObject()` says the type or namespace name cannot be found.

Comment: Use Project > Add Reference > select System.Management

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant says above, in Visual Studio right click your project in Solution Explorer and choose Add Reference. From the .NET tab choose System.Management.